# Hibernate in multi module maven project - could not find specific ehcache configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, caching, ehcache

I am having trouble getting hibernate 2nd level cache to work properly in my project.

I have the following maven structure:

```
myProject
-core
-ui
-pom
```

In my core module I have a session factory configured using hibernate properties.  The ones of concern are:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcacheAdmin.xml</prop>
```

I have unit tests that verify the cache is working correctly.

I add the core module as a jar file to the ui module.  When I do this and start my tomcat server I get the following warning:

```
WARN org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults
```

Can someone help me with this?  I would like the jar file to be solely responsible for querying the database and caching.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `UpdateTimestampsCache` to `ehcache.xml` file.
Search how to configure `UpdateTimestampsCache` [here](http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/hibernate#ehcache-xml).