# How to remove the Ehcache WARN messages when using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, configuration, ehcache

I have this Ehcache XML configuration:

```
<ehcache>
    <defaultCache
            maxElementsInMemory="10000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="120"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"
            overflowToDisk="false"
            diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
            diskPersistent="false"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            />
</ehcache>
```

And also, I have some packages with entities (around 150). If I deploy my application on tomcat server, there is a lot WARN messages in log:

> 2015-04-29 11:59:02,712 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] WARN 
>   org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003:
>   Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named
>   [com.company.project.entity.package.MyEntity]; using defaults.

I can write configuration for each entity -

```
<cache name="com.company.project.entity.package.MyEntity"
                      maxEntriesLocalHeap="50"
                      eternal="false"
                      overflowToDisk="false"
                    timeToLiveSeconds="120">
                <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
        </cache>
```

But in this way, my configuration file become too large (1600 rows). I think there is exist another way to set default config to each entity and kill warn messages, but I don't know how to do it. If anybody know, please help. Many thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this question which appears to describe the same warning that you see? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280073/hibernate-in-multi-module-maven-project-could-not-find-specific-ehcache-config

Comment: two solutions, 1/ kill the log (using log config) or 2/ define a ehcache config for each entity

Comment: Warning `HHH020003` is mentioned [here](https://hahamo.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/ehcache-and-java-ee-6/) and you could try the solution mentioned (set in persistence.xml `<property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value=""/>`).

Comment: This monday I will try to do it.

Comment: @Bobulous, I add UpdateTimestampsCache (org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache for hibernate 4.3.8), but it do nothing (and I can't understand, how http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/index.html#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-hib_configuring_ehcache_settings_for_queries.html%23wwconnect_header can do something with my problem).

Comment: @vanOekel , thanks for your link, but it does not work for me. And this is realy strange, because it's look like my problem. IDK why, may be something was changed in hibernate 4.3.8 (but field hibernate.cache.region_prefix still here http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.8.Final/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.java).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the Hibernate EHCache Cache Region code that logs the warning message:

```
private Ehcache getCache(String name) throws CacheException {
    try {
        Ehcache cache = manager.getEhcache( name );
        if ( cache == null ) {
            LOG.unableToFindEhCacheConfiguration( name );
            manager.addCache( name );
            cache = manager.getEhcache( name );
            LOG.debug( "started EHCache region: " + name );
        }
        HibernateEhcacheUtils.validateEhcache( cache );
        return cache;
    }
    catch (net.sf.ehcache.CacheException e) {
        throw new CacheException( e );
    }

}
```

As you can see, you have two options:

1. You either declare the cache region in the `ehcache.xml` file.
2. You set the 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory' log level to ERROR:

   For Log4j2:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory" level="error">
       <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
   </Logger>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a CacheObject base entity and configure that as your cache object.

Not the cleanest of solution but would remove the warnings without adding a large amount of config.

As the warning is just that, a warning personally i would just configure it to not show.

Comment: good idea, but unfortunatly I'm at home for now. In moday I will test it, hope it will work.